# Creating a .NET incrementing assembly build version in Git

Tags: .net, git, versioning, auto-increment, build-numbers

How do I write a script which will create a source file containing the version number? I would like the build number (4th number in the version quadruple) to be autoincremented for each commit.

I found [some examples](http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/auto-git-versioning) on how to use bash commands to do it:

```
INCREMENT=`git-rev-list $BRANCH..HEAD | wc -l | awk '{print $1}'`
```

but I am using Windows and I don't have a clue how to run that as a script (or a Windows batch file).

I used to work with SVN, and it worked nicely from the command prompt, so I just used it in a batch file, but I don't know how to execute `git-rev-list` without starting `git bash`.

Comment: from where will the script be ran?

Comment: @CharlesB it will be included in the build process, this means a build script or something. When I push the project, I want the version number to be incremented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the git is distributed VCS it is impossible to keep global incremented number, there is no place for it. So, the right thing to do is to use the `<commit sha1>` (or its fragment) as a build number. You could use `git describe` to generate nice version names automatically, including an incremented number.

Another good option is to have a build server (e.g. Jenkins or similar) which has built-in version numbering.

If you want use the hackish approach, you could use git installation, e.g. msysgit, it has all commands such as `ws` or `awk`. Not sure then why your doesn't work, maybe you don't have `Git\bin` folder in your PATH.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, is it possible to get an incrementing number for each `push` to the remote repo? I know I wrote `commit` in my question, but `push` actually makes more sense with versioning. The thing is, with SVN this number would automatically increase and my Setup would always know if a client has an older version installed. With Git, it seems I will have to create these tags manually?

Comment: And the thing is, I have `Git\bin` in my `PATH`. If I enter `git` in my command prompt, it works, but `git-rev-list` doesn't. Is that even an actual command?

Comment: You could have several remote repos. All repos are equal (but some repos are more equal than others). The `git describe` names version in relation to a tag. So, if you have a tag named `v1.2.3` and 15 commits after it, the name will be `v1.2.3-15-g6c28c25`. Just read the documentation.

Comment: @Dilbert use `git rev-list` instead of `git-rev-list`

Comment: Oh, crap, that's pretty obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`AssemblyInfomationalVersionAttribute` may hold any string, including the hash or shorthash or output of `git describe`

Comment: Thanks, but what I wanted is to have an incrementing version number whenever I push my source, so that Windows Installer can know if user has a newer application version already (and it will simplify automatic updates). Otherwise I need to tag the release manually, which I didn't have to do with SVN.

Comment: To automatically generate the last digit, parse the output of git describe to extract the relative number

Comment: You meant, parse the output of `git describe`? Right now it only returns `heads/master`. Do I need to create a tag for this to work?

Comment: At least tag one version as the baseline, such as v1.0. After that, you can git describe [--tags]